# UIView flip transition with show hide animation iOS

Tags: ios, swift, animation, transition, flip

I'm making flip animation from one UIView to another, which is behind first one and hidden. 
code:

```
UIView.transition(from: mediumFirstView, to: mediumSecondView, 
                  duration: 0.5, options: [.transitionFlipFromRight, 
                                           .showHideTransitionViews]) { _ in
    self.mediumFirstView.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
    self.mediumSecondView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
}
```

or this:

```
UIView.transition(with: mediumLimitedView, duration: 0.5, 
                  options: [.transitionFlipFromRight, 
                            .showHideTransitionViews], 
                  animations: {
    self.mediumFirstView.alpha = 0
    self.mediumSecondView.alpha = 1
}) { _ in
    self.mediumFirstView.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
    self.mediumSecondView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
}
```

Problem of both is that First UIView becomes hidden only after full animation of flip, not on half as expected. Am I doing something wrong?

Views hierarchy:

[image: Views hierarchy]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Both of them its working on me. Just replace **mediumFirstView** and **mediumSecondView** location.

```
UIView.transition(from: mediumSecondView, to: mediumFirstView, 
              duration: 5.5, options: [.transitionFlipFromRight, 
                                       .showHideTransitionViews]) { _ in
    self.mediumFirstView.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
    self.mediumSecondView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
}
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: I'm trying to swap from first to second. Your code is replaced them and doesn't work. Do I 'm doing something wrong or you didn't get the question right?

Comment: @Erumaru Can you upload the animation in a picture or gif? I do not know exactly what you want.

Comment: mediumSecondView is hidden and placed right behind mediumFirstView and I want to flip mediumFirstView to mediumSecondView, but my problem is that when I do it by my code above, mediumSecondView becomes visible only after full animation not on half as expected.

Comment: Can you please share view hierarchy for the given solution? Also, please share presets of view (isHidden).

Comment: @Erumaru Ok. I added. I also added UITapGestureRecognizer to my green view to test it.

Comment: I am still facing my problem, so I think problem somewhere else

Answer (score 3):

if you want to animate the visibility

```
UIView.transition(with: mediumLimitedView, duration: 0.5, 
                  options: [.transitionFlipFromRight, 
                            .showHideTransitionViews], 
                  animations: {
    self.mediumFirstView.alpha = 0
    self.mediumSecondView.alpha = 1
}) { _ in
    self.mediumFirstView.isHidden = true
    self.mediumSecondView.isHidden = false
    self.mediumFirstView.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
    self.mediumSecondView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
}
```

If your need is to just to update isHidden - you can setup an scheduled action for t/2 seconds (in your case t is 0.5s seconds so t/2 = 0.25s

```
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.25) {
            [weak self] in
            guard let strongSelf = self else{
                return
            }
            strongSelf.mediumFirstView.isHidden = true
            strongSelf.mediumSecondView.isHidden = false
        }
```

Comment: Did you check your answer? both of them doesn't work.

Comment: Of course, I implemented that for one of my projects.
Try to extend the duration for better debug

Comment: Both of the doing what I explained in question, view swapped only after full animation not at half. What may cause this problem?

Comment: May autolayout cause that problem?